# How to use source-maps in webpack 4 and babel 7?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, source-maps

I'm building a simple config for webpack and babel, I tried to add a source map via

```
 devtool:'eval-cheap-module-source-map'
```

This made a source-map appear but with the file transpiled with babel,
how do I make source-maps reload the js module file in its orginal form?

And another question, how do I enable webpack to make a hot update to the devServer when I change the configuration files, by now every time I change config file I need to run the dev server again. If it's necessary I would upload my config files.